# モデルに対しJSONファイルを一対一で対応させたい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

例えば、Reservationモデルが作成された時に、それに対応するJSONファイルを作成したいです。

Reservationモデルにjsonカラムを追加して、jsonファイルへのpathを格納すればいいと思うのですが、、jsonファイルを作成する方法が分かりません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

作成したファイルは、どこに保存する予定でしょうか? rails が動いているサーバー自体に保存するのは、少し、筋が良くないように思います。

選択肢としては:

- mysql 5.7+ や postgress であるならば、 json 型のカラムが利用可能なので、 reservation に json を保存する。 json 型がなければ、 text 型のカラム作ってそこに保存していおく。
- aws s3 などに upload する

があるかと思います。